# Received "md5" in access logs

Tags: http, apache, md5

In our Apache server we have received around 200 HTTP GET requests from the same IP and a common string in each request is "md5", e.g.

```
index.php?option=com_s5clanroster&view=s5clanroster&layout=category&task=category&id=-null%27+/*!50000UnIoN*/+/*!50000SeLeCt*/md5(3.1415),222--%20- HTTP/1.1
```

What kind of attack hacker had tried over here, and should I worry about it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The attacker is trying to exploit Joomla component called `com_s5clanroster` which is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

> An SQL injection vulnerability has been reported in Joomla Com
>   S5clanroster. Successful exploitation of this vulnerability would
>   allow a remote attacker to execute arbitrary SQL commands on the
>   affected system.

https://www.checkpoint.com/defense/advisories/public/2014/cpai-2014-2169.html

That same component was also vulnerable to LFI:

```
  [o] Exploit

       http://localhost/[path]/index.php?option=com_s5clanroster&view=[LFI]
       http://localhost/[path]/index.php?option=com_s5clanroster&controller=[LFI]
```

http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/39503

Maybe you don't have that component installed or maybe you are running different CMS, but make sure that you check your website is up-to-date. And not only that, also check if different plugins are still maintained by author, because I saw vulnerable plugins with no updates available from author - and that is consider as a big problem.

Here is another example which can lead to another problem: **[Expired Domain Leads to WordPress Plugin Redirects](https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/08/expired-domain-wordpress-plugin-redirects.html)**

Consider to use [ModSecurity](https://modsecurity.org/) (Open Source Web Application Firewall). [How to?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer! I have crosschecked on the server and there is no com_s5clanroster component installed.

Comment: please also tell me about md5 string in the request?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that.

Comment: The MD5 might be a time based attack? It would take some time to compute the MD5 which might be detectable client side?

Comment: In order for the attacker to know that the SQL injection is successful, they want to call a function on the database that has a known result and see if that result is in the output generated.  The choice of md5() specifically is largely irrelevant to the attack.

Comment: And they picked the start of PI as the string to query.